# Рождение формы в любой координате

Tags: c#, форма

Как открыть вторую форму (с фиксированным размером 150*150) в определенной координате (к примеру, верхний-правый угол, левый-правый угол)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [FormStartPosition - перечисление](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition)

> Указывает на первоначальную позицию формы.

- [Control.Location - свойство](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.location)

> Получает или задает координаты левого верхнего угла элемента управления относительно левого верхнего угла контейнера.